# Deadlock without cycle

Tags: java, synchronization, deadlock, petri-net

if I draw a graph that symbolizes all possible calls to blocking functions (java synchronized methods) and I haven't got any cycle in this graph, can I be sure that deadlocks are imposible. Do petri-nets not work like that?

I am not looking for answers like this: Use some monster framework blahblah.

I want to handle my multithreading with synchronized methodes.

EDIT1: The pointed arrows symbolize if one class calls any synchronized method of another class
EDIT2:[klick](http://img852.imageshack.us/i/threads.png/) @here the example, showing a cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider:

```
private static final Semaphore foo = new Semaphore(1);
private static final Semaphore bar = new Semaphore(1);

private static void one() throws InterruptedException {
    foo.acquire();
    bar.acquire();
    bar.release();
    foo.release();
}

private static void two() throws InterruptedException {
    bar.acquire();
    foo.acquire();
    foo.release();
    bar.release();
}
```

See http://pastebin.com/QfK5ZByj for a runnable example. It deadlocks pretty quickly for me.

Comment: Okay this is interesting. If the arrows are lines (pointing in both directions) then it would be a cycle. With single direction arrows it isn't a cycle.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not enough. Suppose you have to threads: A and B. A calls a  method m1 of object o1, which calls method m1 of object o2. Thread B calls method m2 of object o2, which calls method m2 of object o1. Suppose all methods are synchronized. Now, there are concurrent executions of A and B which lead to dead-locks. Although, there is no cyclic call relation between methods.

Is that homework?

Even with your edit regarding class it is not enough, because you can close the cycle through a non synchronized method call.

Comment: Interestingly, if you draw a graph of objects rather than methods, then there is a cycle: o1 -> o2 -> o1. Does that apply to all deadlocks scenarios that don't involve wait/notify? That's probably not an approach which gets you very far in practice, though.

Comment: look at the picutre i edited, it shows what tom describes. I m only talking about connections on object level. My first description was wrong...

Comment: @Franz Kafka: See, the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some methods might block without a `synchronized` key word. This applies to many methods in package `java.util.concurrent` for instance. You should also take into account the `synchronized` blocks inside methods.

If considering only synchronized methods, you can have deadlocks without cycle in methods calls, as the synchronized methods use the object instance as a monitor. For instance if you have two objects A and B, each one with synchronized methods 1() and 2(). If A.1() calls B.1() and B.2() calls A.2(), although there is no cycle in methods, if a thread calls `B.2()` at the same time an other calls `A.1()` then there is a deadlock risk.

Comment: Okay I think I explained it wrong. I was talking about drawing a pointed arrow if one class calls another. So arrows are on class level and not methode level. But I only consider drawing arrows if a synchronized class is used. Do you know what I mean? :-)